# Как типизировать пропсы children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Как типизировать пропсы children? Нужно получить пропсы из children

Выходит такая ошибка:
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | true | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.   Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
interface IProps {
    children: React.ReactNode,
}

const Component: FC<IProps> = (props) => {

   let data = props.children ? props.children.props : [];

   return (
      <>
      </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Вроде никак в этой ситуации